# Move to exactly a certain distance from an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, game-physics

My camera is looking to an object `A`. When I move the mouse up or down or I scroll the mouse wheel, the camera gets closer or further to `A`.

```
//frontal movement
Vector3 frontal = transform.forward * 
                  (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") + Input.mouseScrollDelta.y) * 
                  0.3f;

//distance from the camera to the object
if(Vector3.Distance(A.position, transform.position + frontal) > minDistance)
    transform.position += frontal;
```

The point is: I don't want the camera to get very close to `A`, so I defined a float `minDistance` that states the minimum distance the camera can be from the object.

**The problem:** my code simply says: "If the final position is closer than `minDistance`, don't move". This is not the behaviour I want. If the final position is closer than `minDist`, I want it to move to the point where the dist is exactly `minDist`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the normalized vector difference between your camera and the object relative to the object (this gives the "angle" vector). Check if the distance is less than `minDistance`, and if so, move the camera to the position of the target offset by `angle * minDistance`:

```cs
Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + frontal;
Vector3 difference = newPosition - A.position;
float distance = difference.magnitude;

if (distance < minDistance) 
{
  Vector3 angle = difference.normalized;
  transform.position = A.position + (angle * minDistance);
}
else
{
  transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

(There are a few ways to optimize this, such as comparing distance-squared rather than distance which eliminates an unnecessary square-root operation.)

Comment: In fact I'm looking for the most optimized option out there, because I'll run this test every frame.

Comment: I've just edited your answer to something that works fine and seems a bit smaller. Do you think this can be optimized? Do you think that creating the forward vector in realtime (subtracting `A.position - newPosition` and normalizing) is faster than calling `transform.forward`?

Comment: @Daniel Your edit has several typos and doesn't normalize the difference vector, so this code wouldn't work even if it compiled. And while this reduction would technically count as an optimization, I would label it squarely under the "micro-optimization" category and, unless benchmarks view it as absolutely necessary, code neatness and readability is preferable to conciseness and shaving off a few nanoseconds. And for future reference, it's considered quite rude to edit an answer just to give your own "personal take" on the solution. If you have a suggestion for improvement, post a comment.

Comment: Yes, it would work and there wasn't typos, in fact it's the code I'm using now and it's working fine. `transform.forward` is a  normal vector, doesn't need to be normalized. I'm not very interested in readability since it's my own project, my biggest focus is speed.

Comment: @Daniel `tansform.position`.

Comment: Oh, that? You could have added an **r** instead of reverting all. It was not a "personal take", is a smaller and more efficient version using the same idea you had.

Comment: @Daniel I reverted it because A) it's my answer and I personally prefer code readability over a micro-optimization that might save .005 milliseconds per frame at most, and B) it was rude of you to edit someone else's answer without permission in the first place. If you disagree with my reasoning, feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: If code readability was the deciding factor, do you think my edit made it any worse? I'll not extend this discussion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Daniel I do. That may be a subjective statement, but the fact that I had to stare at it for 15 - 20 seconds piecing together what it did means your code is not self-documenting, which means it isn't very readable unless you already know what it does. Again, don't seek to micro-optimize. I brought up the distance-squared over distance optimization because replacing a square root with simple arithmetic is a huge optimization that is always worth doing when possible. Eliminating a few variable assignments is not. (Ironically, what I suggested was the one optimization you did _not_ adopt.)

Comment: @Daniel I've been thinking about your approach, and I wanted to chime in on the usage of `transform.forward` that's been bugging me. That vector represents the forward-facing vector of the camera, and that would only correspond to the angle vector between the camera and the object `A` if the camera was pointed directly at `A`. If you can guarantee that to always be the case, it would be an adequate substitution, but `transform.forward` cannot replace `(newPosition - A.position).normalized` in the general case.